# C++ bitwise bools

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, operation

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to create a Boolean type which suits byte operations.
for example:

```
unsigned char TRUE_BOOL = ~unsigned char(0);
unsigned char FALSE_BOOL = unsigned char(0);
```

Now I want to have the following expression return one of the defined BOOL's- so if for example I use the expression `5 < 10` this will return one of my bitwise BOOL's rather than the standard bools. I want this in order to be able to replace if statements with bitwise operations :

```
//---------------parameter definitions
unsigned char a = 10;
unsigned char b = 20;

//---------------if statement approach
if(a < b){
    unsigned char Result = 13;
}else{
    unsigned char Result = 17;
}

//---------------bitwise approach
unsigned char Result = ((a < b) & 13) | ((a >= b) & 17);
```

What are some of the ways this (i.e returning my BOOL rather than the standard) could be implemented? I have some ideas but I wanted to know if perhaps some better approach exists.

Comment: Implement your own class for numerics, then you will be able to control the return type of operations.

Comment: Is there any reason you want this over actual C++ `bool`?

Comment: That's what the wonky `std::vector<bool>` template specialization does.  Might as well use it.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: why do you need such thing, are they involved in bitwise operations? Because otherwise automatic bool and "char" bool have no difference

Comment: @Yksisarvinen to avoid branching which might make it run faster ( potentially?)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I wish to avoid the branching of if/else, this procedural method potentially could speed things up. Also I will just add that I don't "need" such a thing, I wrote in my post that I "want" to do it.

Comment: Even if you find a way to implement this you won't reduce branching, you'll increase it because there will be a branch inside the implementation of `a < b` and another inside `a >= b`. Write readable code that is simple and works and let the compiler optimiser do it's job "clever" code can be harder for the compiler to optimise. Only when you've finished and profiled your code and found a particular area is causing a real performance issue should you resort to micro optimisations, even then algorithmic changes are likely to produce better results

Comment: @AlanBirtles there is actually way to implement comparisons as bitwise ops without branching and it possible to produce all 0 or all 1 bits that way directly, but that's wonky, unnecessary and becomes an overly expensive micro optimization which I suspect is early at this stage. Provided, compiler _may_ actually generate branchless code where applicable

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom boolean class that does result in `~0` or `0` when implicitly converted to an unsigned int, like so:

```
class BOOL {
    unsigned int value;

public:
    BOOL(bool value): value(value ? ~0 : 0) {}

    operator unsigned int() {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Then you could write:

```
unsigned char Result = (BOOL(a < b) & 13) | (BOOL(a >= b) & 17);
```

Which does what you want. I wouldn't recommend this however, as the compiler will already do these kinds of optimizations for you. For example, instead of using the above way of writing the expression with the `&`-operator, you could instead write:

```
unsigned char Result = ((a < b) * 13) | ((a >= b) * 17);
```

But as mentioned in the comments, the lack of `if`-statements doesn't mean this couldn't still contains conditional branches. One thing to note though is that the difference between `13` and `17` is just `4` You could thus write:

```
unsigned char Result = 13 + ((a >= b) << 2);
```

All these approaches are optimized by the compiler to generate the exact same instructions, as can be seen on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:22,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:22,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:22,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:22),source:%27class+BOOL+%7B%0A++++unsigned+int+value%3B%0Apublic:%0A++++BOOL(bool+value):+value(value+%3F+%7E0+:+0)+%7B%7D%0A++++operator+unsigned+int()+%7B%0A++++++++return+value%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+using_custom_class(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++return+(BOOL(a+%3C+b)+%26+13)+%7C+(BOOL(a+%3E%3D+b)+%26+17)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+using_multiplication(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++return+((a+%3C+b)+*+13)+%7C+((a+%3E%3D+b)+*+17)%3B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+using_addition_and_shift(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++return+13+%2B+((a+%3E%3D+b)+%3C%3C+2)%3B%0A%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:36.25839793281654,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:30.68112476711188,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:10,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.060477300071575,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: I am not sure you understood my question.  `unsigned char Result = ((a < b) & 13) | ((a >= b) & 17);`  does exactly what I want as I have tested it. what I wanted to do was have the expression `a < b` evaluate to a byte filled with `11111111` when true or a byte filled with `00000000` when false. And then everything evaluates the way I specified. The question was not whether it works, but how to implement `<`  such that it returns `11111111` when true and `00000000` when false - under those conditions everything I wrote will work - you can test it as well.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you wanted. I added an example of using a class to convert `bool` to/from an `unsigned int` with all bits either set or unset, is that what you had in mind?